# can not create RPM using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, rpm, jacoco

I am new to java/gradle setup and was able to build a jar file using example provided [here](http://johnathanmarksmith.com/java/gradle/2015/02/04/how-to-create-a-runnable-jar-file-with-gradle/). Also implemented Jacoco code coverage tool on same.
But running into following issue

- Unable to build an RPM, Tried ospackage-plugin but its just doesnt generates anything ( used example provided on plugin's github page )
- Jacoco not generating highlighted source code html files ? Its generating till method breakdown like [this](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/coverage/org.jacoco.examples/org.jacoco.examples/CoreTutorial$TestTarget.html) but not able to generate individual source code files

My build.gradle file is as below

```
plugins {
  id "nebula.ospackage" version "3.2.0"
} 

apply plugin: 'nebula.ospackage'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8'
  compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
}

sourceSets {
     main {
        java {       srcDir 'src/main/java/'      }
        resources {  srcDir 'src/main/resources'  }
     }

   test {
        java {       srcDir 'src/test/java/'      }
        resources {  srcDir 'src/test/resources'  }
    }
}

test {
    // explicitly include or exclude tests
    include 'src/test/java/**'

    useTestNG{
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }

    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}


jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'smith'
    version = '1.0'
    manifest {
              attributes 'Main-Class': 'src.main.java.HelloWorld '}
}

ospackage {
    packageName = 'foo'
        version = '1.2.3'
        release = '1'
        arch = I386
        os = LINUX
}

// buildRpm and buildDeb are implicitly created, but can still be configured if needed

buildRpm {
    arch = I386
}
```

The STDOUT is as following

```
project]$ /opt/gradle/bin/gradle  build
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test
:jacocoTestReport
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.258 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon:     https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

Any pointers on whatever i am overlooking above will be highly appreciated. 
Also feel free to let me know in case any standard/convention is not followed

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to run the `buildRpm` task.

```
gradle buildRpm
```

If you want this task to run when running `gradle build` just configure a dependency in your *build.gradle* file

```
build.dependsOn buildRpm
```

Comment: Thank you ... that did the trick , i assumed buildRPM will run on its own.

Comment: Hi Mark, On trying to install the RPM created i am getting the below error     
    ```sudo yum install build/distributions/project-unspecified-3.noarch.rpm   
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror   
    error: /home/vagrant/testng/project/build/distributions/project-unspecified-3.noarch.rpm: headerRead failed: hdr load: BAD 
    Cannot open: build/distributions/project-unspecified-3.noarch.rpm. Skipping.      Error: Nothing to do

Comment: The error message may have been due to not adding any files to the RPM.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can add below variables in your rpm task to make your RPM more standard

    `requires('package name')     //required package to run your RPM to be pre installed, will fail if it is not.
    preInstall('path_to_file')     //script to be executed before installing RPM
    preUninstall('path_to_file')   //script to be executed before uninstalling RPM
    postInstall('path_to_file')    //script to be executed after installing RPM
    preUninstall('path_to_file')   // script to be executed after uninstalling RPM`

```
archiveName    //the name you want to give to your RPM.
epoch          //Epoch, defaults to 0
user           //Default user to permission files to
permissionGroupdisplay 
packageGroup
buildHost
summary
packageDescription
license
packager
distribution
vendor
url
type    //type e.g. binary
//below three variables are used for signing of the RPM
signingKeyId
signingKeyPassphrase
signingKeyRingFile
sourcePackage

//if you want to include some files in your rpm
def fileToInclude = fileTree(dir:"pathToFile", include : "file" ) 
from (fileToInclude) {
     fileMode 0500 // file level permission
     into "installation Location" //locationToPlaceTheFile
}
```

for more details and e.g. refer [this](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/RPM-Plugin) link